# If $y=\lvert\cos x\rvert+\lvert\sin x\rvert$, then what is $dy/dx$ at $x=2\pi/3$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, absolute-value

Can you help me understand this?

> If $y=\lvert\cos x\rvert+\lvert\sin x\rvert$ then at
> $x=2\pi/3$, what is $dy/dx$?

The answer is $(\sqrt{3}-1)/3$, but how?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you think about the signs of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ you will notice that one or other changes sign only when $ x $ is at multiple of $\pi/2$.  Otherwise, neither is changing sign and so at and around every other point $y$ can be written without modulus signs in one the four forms $\pm\sin x + \pm\cos x$.  At these points it is differentiable using the usual rules for differentiating trigonometric functions.  You just need to decide when $x=2\pi/3$ which sign combination is appropriate.

Comment: should the absolute value even matter? can't we differentiate directly since absolute values are always positive? the equation is simply y=cosx+sinx

Comment: **A**ll, **S**ine, **T**angent, **C**osine. Sine is negative in the third and fourth quadrants, cosine is negative in the second and third quadrants. Tangent is negative in the second and fourth quadrants. $2\pi/3$ is in the second quadrant, so cosine is negative and sine is positive.

Comment: The only clarification I would add is: Differentiation is a local operation so you only need to think about the behaviour of the function in a small neighbourhood about the point. In this case the point is $x=2\pi /3$. Very close to this point, $\sin x$ is positive and $\cos x$ is negative. Because of this, we can replace the absolute value signs as follows $|\sin x|+|\cos x|= \sin x -\cos x$. So the derivative is $\cos x+\sin x$. Evaluating this at the point gives you the answer.

Comment: $(\sqrt3-1)/2$ maybe...

Comment: Answer your own question "should the absolute value even matter" by actually sketching the graph of the function. Try to understand stuff, not just use rules.